# Writing integer to file descriptor using write()?

Tags: c, file, char, size, system-calls

I am trying to write an integer to a file using the file descriptor.
I tried doing :

```
fd is the file descriptor
int i = 17;
write(fd, &i, sizeof i);
// doesn't get written
```

however chars get printed if I do

```
    char c = 'a';
    write(fd, &c, sizeof c);
```

How can I directly write the integer, without using any external function. Please note that I only want to use a file descriptor.

Comment: Is it simply impossible ?

Comment: Your first example does print the integer to the file, assuming that `fd` is a valid, open file descriptor. The problem is that it will write it in binary form, ie not as `"17"`, but as `"\x11\0\0\0"` (assuming a little endian machine).

Comment: If you're on a recent Unix system, you can use `dprintf(fd, "%d\n", i)` as a version of `fprintf()` which does not require you to use stdio streams. But __just like the `write()` libc wrapper__, it's __not__ a syscall, you would still have to link with the standard C library. And just like `printf()` (but unlike `write()`), `dprintf()` may use `malloc()`, is not reentrant and cannot be used from signal handlers.